# cron job not executing the binary in the time specified

Tags: crontab, cronjob

I would like to check which is the environment being used if executing a cron job. I had it working before however it stopped at some point.

This is my cron job in the crontab file:

```
20 13 * * * /usr/bin/env >> /home/user/folder1/environment1.log
```

With this line, I am expecting to dump the environment variables to the environment1.log file.

Does anybody have a suggestion of what to check?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have found a link on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/how-to-log-cron-jobs) related to this.
It is suggested to add  2>&1 to the end like:

`* * * * * myjob.sh >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1`

to correctly handle the redirection of the output. Some more information on the '2>&1' [here.](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/)

---

A few things to check:

- Does the user who is running the job have access to write to that location?
- Can you run the command in the command line, and do you get the correct output?
- Can you write the output to /tmp/some_filename.log?
- The line you have implies the job will run at 13:20. Is this the time you were expecting?

Comment: yes to all the questions

Answer (score 0):

You can check the cron log to see if the event fired or not. On my centos unix, the path is:

```
/var/log/cron
```

I also have it configured so that the log rotate keeps around 30 days of logs, so I can check if something goes wrong.

The other thing I'd check is if the cron service is running. In Centos:

```
service crond status
```

You can also check it with:

```
ps -ef | grep crond
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my OS is Red Hat SunOS
Unfortunately I do not have the directory `/var/log/cron`. It looks like service binary is not used in this OS. Finally If execute the command `ps -ef | grep "cron"` I see one process running

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984725/how-to-test-a-weekly-cron-job